# How to track email?

Tags: gmail, imap, tracking, yahoo

I'm creating a web platform of emails using gmail/yahoo. My goal is to create a platform that will manage my clients, emails and other data of my business.

I would like to know if is possible to track a sended email to change status when the person opens the email. Is possible to do that? (sending the information to my platform?)

How can I do that?

Comment: no, not without user approval and/or remote mail server cooperation. it'd be a major security/privacy violation.

Comment: How Streak Plugin or GA Track works? ('cause both do that)

Comment: exactly how are you going to get your email to "reach out" to your server? mail clients don't load external resources automatically anymore for this very reason, and a mail client isn't going to execute JS code in the mail.

Comment: @MarcB That was exactly what I thought (or knew). But when I saw that Streak Plugin for Chrome and GA Track do that, I thought: "is it possible?! 'Cause both do that. If they do, there is a way!" Streak for example, bring to me the information of when email was opened, the location, the device...